# bash script to unzip recently uploaded file into server

Tags: bash, unzip

I want to unzip file automatically after being uploaded into server.
I'm not experienced in bash but I've tried this

```
for file in *.zip
do
unzip -P pcp9100 "$file" -d ./ 
done
```

It's not working as I want.

Comment: You tried above code, what happened then? Where you happy with the results? If not, why not? What was the expected result? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That works fine for me. Does that not perform the intended result? If not, what is is supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, assuming you want this to be continuously done in a loop, you can do something like:

```
while true; do
    for file in *.zip; do
        unzip -P pcp9100 "${file}" -d ./
        rm "${file}"
    done
    sleep 3
done
```

Of course there are several things that can go wrong here.

- File has an incorrect password
- The file inside is also a zip file and does not have the same password
- Permissions are incorrect

First, your permissions should be correct. Secondly, you can create a directory called "ExtractedFiles" and one called "IncorrectPasswords" which you can do something like:

```
while true; do
    for file in *.zip; do
        unzip -P pcp9100 "${file}" -d ./ExtractedFiles || mv "${file}" ./IncorrectPasswords
        rm "${file}"
    done
    sleep 3
done
```